# RemoveObjectAtIndex for NSMuatableArray of NSmutableArrays in iOS is crashing

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am using `NSMutableArray` and trying to the remove the object from the `NSMutableArray` then it is crashing at

**[[self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];**

`.h` is like

```
NSMutableArray *sectionsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sectionsArray;



.m is like:

 @synthesize sectionsArray;

 #pragma mark - TableView Delegate

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
// Perform segue to candy detail
  
NSLog(@"section: %d row: %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"section :%@", [[self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
[[self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
  
 }
```

crash log is like :

```
 2014-01-28 11:56:24.989 CandySearch[828:c07] section: 2 row: 0
 2014-01-28 11:56:24.991 CandySearch[828:c07] section :<Candy: 0x75a5a70>
 2014-01-28 11:56:24.992 CandySearch[828:c07] -[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75d8c90
 2014-01-28 11:56:24.992 CandySearch[828:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75d8c90'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (0x1c9b012 0x10d8e7e 0x1d264bd 0x1c8abbc 0x1c8a94e 0x370d 0xcc285 0xcc4ed 0xad65b3 0x1c5a376 0x1c59e06 0x1c41a82 0x1c40f44 0x1c40e1b 0x1bf57e3 0x1bf5668 0x1cffc 0x1d52 0x1cc5 0x1)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I can see the object at that index.but still it is crashing
why?

Comment: you have index based section in your tableview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array that sits on index "indexPath.section" is an NSArray object, and not an NSMutableArray 
Just read the crashlog:
**NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:**

Please check the objects of your sectionsArray

Comment: NSMutableArray *sortedSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:unsortedSections.count];
    for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections) {
        [sortedSections addObject:[collation sortedArrayFromArray:section collationStringSelector:@selector(description)]];
    }
    self.sectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedSections]; iam using like this

Answer (score 0):

You are tring to call `removeObjectAtIndex:` in **immutable array(NSArray)**. That's why, It lead to crash. (that's, section array is mutable but it having array of immutable array objects.)

Answer (score 0):

Mine mutable array object was also causing crash as it was being assigned an NSArray. So, I got the issue fixed by using

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]
```